# Remove repeated years from x-axis in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have draw a bar chart in plotly (python). The year value `2019` is repeated along y-axis. How can I display only one `2019` in the middle not others.

[image]

My code:

```
        a = pd.DataFrame(a.groupby(by=['Year', 'Vendor Name']) 
        ['Spend'].sum())
       
        fig_2 = px.bar(a, x='Year', y='Spend', 
        color='Vendor Name', barmode='stack', text='Spend')
        fig_2.update_traces(marker_line_width=0)
        fig_2.update_layout(
                    title="",
                    xaxis_title="",
                    yaxis_title="Total Spend",
                    legend_title="Vendor names",
                    height=450,
                    width=700,
                    
                    )
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Please post it here.

Comment: Is the data type of the year of the x-axis set to a string?

Comment: @r-beginners, No, it is in type of datetime

Comment: Try this out `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`, you may have to convert the data type of the year to be plotted to a string.

Comment: @Priya, Thanks very much, this is the answer that I looked for. I have one other question. In this case it show year as `2019-06-15T00:00:00` along y-axis. How can I display only year `2019` along y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
a['year'] = a['date'].dt.year
```

gives the column with only the year part, the actual date column should be of `datetime` though. Then maybe you could do

```
fig2.update_xaxez(type="category")
```